# How to get second or first part of email address in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column in my table saving the email addresses.

1. How to select the first part of it (before the '@')?
2. How to select the second part of it (after the '@')?
3. What does the following `WHERE` statement do in Redshift (email_add is the column saving the email-addresses in the table)?

   `SELECT blablabla WHERE SUBSTRING(email_add,1,DECODE(POSITION('@' IN email_add),0,2,POSITION('@' IN email_add)-1)) IN ('arzt','zahnarzt','heilpraktiker','orthopaed','facharzt','praxis','gynaekol','klinik')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 and 2, `split_part` (Split string on delimiter and return the given field (counting from one). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html:

```
SELECT split_part('abc@def.com', '@', 1); -- abc
SELECT split_part('abc@def.com', '@', 2); -- def.com
```

Comment: redshift <> postgres. but in this case the solution works. you should reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html rather than the postgres docs.

Comment: Thanks for both of you! Does this works if I give the column-name instead of the string directly as you did ('abd@def.com')? So I replace that with email_add (email_add is the name of the column containing the email-addresses)?

Comment: Yes. its just easier to demonstrate using string literals.